# Activity does not starts

Tags: android, android-activity

When i press button to start new activity, applications goes to main activity instead.
I am really confused because, there is no any error. Also I have log message in On create of desired activity - it does not pop up. Can you please tell me what can cause such strange behaviour?

```
    public void btnAtcEdit(View v) {
        Log.d("ATS", "i tried to go to ATS believe me");
        try {
            Log.d("ATS", " i tried to go to ATS 2 believe me");
            // convert bitmap to bytearray to pass them in intent
            final BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable1 = (BitmapDrawable) photo1
                    .getDrawable();
            final Bitmap yourBitmap1 = bitmapDrawable1.getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            yourBitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream1);
            byte[] imm1 = stream1.toByteArray();

            final BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable2 = (BitmapDrawable) photo2
                    .getDrawable();
            final Bitmap yourBitmap2 = bitmapDrawable2.getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            yourBitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream2);
            byte[] imm2 = stream2.toByteArray();

            final BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable3 = (BitmapDrawable) photo3
                    .getDrawable();
            final Bitmap yourBitmap3 = bitmapDrawable3.getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream3 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            yourBitmap3.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream3);

            byte[] imm3 = stream3.toByteArray();
            Intent i = new Intent(AddToCheckActivity.this,
            AddSaveActivity.class);

            i.putExtra("photo1", imm1);
            /*
                        putting more parameters
                        */
            i.putExtra("not_priceFor", not_priceFor);

            startActivity(i);
            stream1.flush();
            stream1.close();
            stream2.flush();
            stream2.close();
            stream3.flush();
            stream3.close();
//          finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ATS error", "before entered ATS");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

AddSaveActivity

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.aadd_add_edit);
        Log.d("ATS", "was started");
                /*
                some job
                */
                }
```

Log cat is empty It just shos, that button was pressed.

```
08-07 11:32:28.250: D/ATS(19968): i tried to go to ATS believe me
08-07 11:32:28.250: D/ATS(19968):  i tried to go to ATS 2 believe me
08-07 11:32:28.992: I/dalvikvm-heap(19968): Grow heap (frag case) to 22.075MB for 414640-byte allocation
08-07 11:32:29.054: D/dalvikvm(19968): GC_CONCURRENT freed 940K, 28% free 17454K/24111K, paused 15ms+3ms, total 59ms
08-07 11:32:29.187: E/Trace(20764): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-07 11:32:29.203: V/ActivityThread(20764): Class path: /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend-2.apk, JNI path: /data/data/ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend/lib
08-07 11:32:29.398: D/dalvikvm(20764): GC_CONCURRENT freed 89K, 22% free 9913K/12651K, paused 14ms+2ms, total 38ms
08-07 11:32:29.398: D/dalvikvm(20764): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 10ms
08-07 11:32:29.414: D/login(20764): -- 0
08-07 11:32:29.468: D/libEGL(20764): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
08-07 11:32:29.492: D/libEGL(20764): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
08-07 11:32:29.492: D/libEGL(20764): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
08-07 11:32:29.656: D/OpenGLRenderer(20764): Enabling debug mode 0
```

onClickListener for button is defiend in xml

```
 <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAtcEdic"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_primary"
                android:drawablePadding="0sp"
                android:onClick="btnAtcEdit"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:text="Редактировать"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Interesting thing - always works without any sign of error on HTC phons.

**EDIT:** after i moved imm form intent to singleton, app seems to work properly

Comment: From where "btnAtcEdit" is called? How do you setup your button's click listener?

Comment: post logcat for proper suggestion

Comment: What is `not_priceFor` and how do you declare and use it (besides the `putExtra()`)? And why don't you use `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` ?

Comment: try changing `Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    AddSaveActivity.class);` to `Intent(yourCurrentCLass.this,
                    AddSaveActivity.class);`

Comment: yourCurrentCLass.this did not change anything; not_priceFor is string used to fill textviews;btnAtcEdit onClickListener is defined in xml; Logcat does not shows any errors

Comment: imm is small bitmap ~ 15kb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was imposed by bytearrays. Intent is not suppossed to be used to transmit large ammount of data. After I moved bytearrays from intent to singleton class I have not had that problem any more.

Answer (score 1):

You can't start an Activity using the Application Context. You can only start them with another Activity Context.

The following change should fix this. Substitute your Activity name for <YourCallingActivity>

```
Intent i = new Intent(<YourCallingActivity>.this, AddSaveActivity.class);
```

For reference, here is a guide on which kind of context is needed in which place:

http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/?utm_source=Android+Weekly&utm_campaign=78ad4cb95e-Android_Weekly_64&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-78ad4cb95e-335181433

Comment: hm.. so if you words are true, my application should not work at all, but i have problems only with one module.

Comment: by the way i changed it to Intent i = new Intent(AddToCheckActivity.this,
    AddSaveActivity.class); and there is no benefit

Comment: Did you make sure to add a reference to this Activity in your manifest? Also, is that really all the logcat from this error? Perhaps you are filtering the logcat and missing something?

Comment: sure. If i did not i would have exeption. Also in that case app would not work on other devices

Answer (score 0):

U can try:

```
            stream1.flush();
            stream1.close();
            stream2.flush();
            stream2.close();
            stream3.flush();
            stream3.close();

 Intent i = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,
                    AddSaveActivity.class);

            i.putExtra("photo1", imm1);
            /*
                        putting more parameters
                        */
            i.putExtra("not_priceFor", not_priceFor);

            startActivity(i);
```